# Delphi D.P.F. iOS data pickers stop working on iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, iphone, delphi, delphi-xe8

Have a big problem with linking simple text field to an alternative data input view in iOS application.

In my project I use D.P.F. iOS components (whole project is built on them). To simplify lets say on the form I have a text field tfTextField and date picker dpDatePicker. It is written everywhere that alternative input (getting data not from a standard keyboard but something else) can be set through the InputView property (in Delphi it is implemented through the procedure setInputView). So this linking was made like this:

`UITextField(tfTextField.UIControl).setInputView(UIDatepicker(dpDatePicker.UIControl));`

And this was working for a long-long time without any problems. But now, after the last updates, this code brakes the application with error

`Project dyld_sim raised exception class SIGABRT (6).`

(error catched on an iOS 8.4 simulator).
The most interesting thing is that this code is still working on iOS 7.1 simulator, that runs from the same xCode 6.4.

Error appears when I try to enter the text field. Normally there should be called date picker, but application crashes without any message. It was also tested on an iPhone with a new iOS (8.4).

Can please anybody help me with this issue? Maybe such way of linking is wrong? I tried to find a solution in original Swift's manuals, but cannot port them into Delphi - all I get are Access Violation errors.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: It was made several years ago by another man. Now I have to support this project and it's just impossible to rebuild it on iOS-native Swift. Unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, forgot. Delphi XE8, MAC OS 10.10.5, xCode 6.4.

Comment: It's not going to be impossible. But this is perhaps a consequence of using these third party controls.

Comment: I think you're going to need to produce a small compiling test case and/or the Swift code you're trying to port. In principle you should be able to translate given the DPF components (unlike most FMX controls) are (very thin) wrappers round native Cocoa Touch Objective-C objects